# I have an issue with ProtonVPNv3 CLI on my server, in which I can not get a connection

Tags: networking, router, vpn

My server is connected to the household router via power-line adapters and a leased DHCP. I have been trying to get Proton VPN to establish a connection for a few days but I can not get it to work.

First I attempted to get with Proton support, and they have been fantastic, but is still throwing them for a loop as well.

First it is important to note I am runnning Debian 12 using LXDE, so I do not inherently have the nm-applet. Now, we tried running initially:

```
sudo nmcli dev set eno0 managed yes
```

But it still did not work correctly. Next we tried to implement Open VPN, and I chose TCP (for reliability), and it still did not work. I checked the household gateway's configuration page and it does not appear that any of the TCP utilized ports are closed.

This router is not my router, so port forwarding is not an real option.

Comment: Why do you need to set up port-forwarding? You are connecting out to an external server, not accepting connections yourself, right?

Comment: Oh yes, this is my personal server, I'm building a home lab. So the connections are being received by my server. A VPN would allow me to connect without opening up any ports on the household router.